# Where can I find exactly how Tensorflow does matrix multiplication?

Tags: tensorflow

For example, I want to do a matrix multiplication, and in doing so, I use the tf.matmul operation inside the tensorflow. And, i want to optimize matrix mulptiplication in tf. However, I cannot reach where the matrix Multiplication is made exactly in tf_matmul. Is there any people who can help me to do this ?

Comment: The documentation for adding new ops https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op may be relevant for looking at existing ops as well.

Answer (score 1):

We need to do some code tracing to figure out what is being called and what is happening

1) [tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L1945) called via `tf.matmul`

2) `tf.matmul` returns either a `sparse_matmul` (which calls `gen_math_ops.sparse_matmul`) or `gen_math_ops.batch_mat_mul`

3) The `gen_math_ops` script is automatically generated but the underlying code is [math_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc)

All the best!

Comment: Maybe OP needs not the script, but the kernel code e.g. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/core/kernels/batch_matmul_op_impl.h

Comment: So  i can the exact place of pure matrix multiplication in  math_ops.cc or ? I wholly check it but i didn't find for loops for matrix multiplication.

Comment: I don't mean to sound like a dick but what exactly are you trying to do? What exactly makes you so sure that your optimization will beat Googles? I wholly support what you're doing even if it's just to learn but I've been down this rabbit hole before